# Multiple checkboxes horizontally in flex-layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got some checkboxes set horizontally in my form. They are dynamically set, so the amount can change. I've used flex, and flex wrap to allow the checkboxes to wrap to the next line. Here is the html:

```css
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap {
  min-width: 12em;
  max-width: 12em;
}
```

```html
<div [hidden]="hidden">
  {{label}}
  <div class="form-group pl-4 mb-0">
    <div class="wrap" *ngFor="let enum of this.enumArray">
      <input [id]="enum" type="checkbox" (input)="getValue($event)" (change)="onChange($event)" value="enum" class=" form-check-input mt-1">
      <label class="form-check-label">{{enum}}</label>
    </div>
    <span class="description">{{description}}</span>
    <span class="error-msg">{{error}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The checkboxes look great, until the last line where 3 or 4 of them somehow become unaligned. Even if I have 10 or 100 checkboxes the last line is always unaligned. Here is an example of what I mean:
[Here is the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLVwv.png)

If I could get some guidance as to what is happening I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please post a [example].

Comment: Given the `{{label}}` there seems to be some library or other code in play here?  Perhaps add a tag for that.  Consider posting the rendered HTML fragment with at least the minimal number to reproduce this here as an alternative  since that is what the CSS will apply to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your method of justifying the content to force the child divs to fill the extra space. This is a simple alternative:

```
.form-group{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrap{
  flex: 0 0 12em;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much. I'll have to keep this in mind when using flex layout.

Comment: Glad it helps. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is an excellent resource on using flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Using [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) might be a better solution to this problem. It looks like the last line doesn't have the same number of elements as the previous lines and the elements are stretching to fill the space.

If you want to use `flex`, you could set a `max-width` on the child elements, but this does seem like a great use case for `grid`. Here's how I'd start:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
```

This will create 6 equally-sized columns. You could also check out [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for more info and help with grid.

Comment: This is also a viable solution as well. Didn't think that I was essentially creating a grid using flex layout. Thanks for your input!